# Custom option Menu

Tags: android

I have created one custom menu in fragment, and it is working fine, but problem is when i go back, that menu is display in all activity and fragment, i dont want it to display in all, so help me out.

```
public class DriverLogDetialsFragment extends Fragment {
            private MainActivity mainActivity;

            public DriverLogDetialsFragment() {
                // Required empty public constructor
            }

            public static DriverLogDetialsFragment newInstance(MainActivity mainActivity) {
                DriverLogDetialsFragment fragment = new DriverLogDetialsFragment();
                fragment.mainActivity = mainActivity;
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driverlog_detials, container, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_log_detials, menu);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.action_email) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_email, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder bulider = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    bulider.setView(view);
                    bulider.setCancelable(false);
                    bulider.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    bulider.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    bulider.show();
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }


        }
```

Comment: @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_comment,menu);
}      in other fragmnets just write menu.clear();

Comment: i dont have menu in other fragments..